# One side TCP ESTABLISHED connection

Tags: linux, tcp

On the Server `10.10.3.171` I use netstat to find clients :

```
$ netstat -ant | grep 24225 | grep 10.10.3.169

tcp        0      0 10.10.3.171:24225       10.10.3.169:58591       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.10.3.171:24225       10.10.3.169:60428       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.10.3.171:24225       10.10.3.169:56334       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.10.3.171:24225       10.10.3.169:48077       ESTABLISHED
```

But on the Client `10.10.3.169`, there is no any connection to server:

```
$ netstat -na | grep 10.10.3.171 | grep 24225
```

Can somebody explain what's happened?

PS : `10.10.3.171` is a real server behind LVS.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `netstat -na | grep 10.10.3.171` ?

Comment: Of course, there are some connections to `10.10.3.171`, but connect to another port in `10.10.3.171`.